# How to access object reference using string in c#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
public interface IWebElement {
    void Click(string txt);
}

public class TextField : IWebElement {
    public void Click (string txt) {
        Console.WriteLine(txt);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IWebElement obj = new TextField();

        'obj'.Click("hi") // Is der any way to achieve something like this
    }
}
```

Is there any way to access **object reference** as a **string** in c#. Here 'obj' is a object string. I am trying to implement common Please help me to resolve my problem.

I want to achieve this in selenium testing framework.

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "TitleId")]
        public IWebElement ddlTitleID { get; set; }

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Initial")]
    public IWebElement txtInitial { get; set; }


    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "FirstName")]
    public IWebElement txtFirstName { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Save")]
    public IWebElement btnSave { get; set; }
```

Selenium will call using a function

```
 function clickSave () {
      btnSave.click();
 }


 function clickFirstName () {
      txtFirstName.click();
 }
```

Instead i am trying to acheive like this

```
function clickEvent(ObjRefernce) {

   'ObjReference'.click()
}
```

you can create object like this to access this i need to write a test case so i have create function for each and every object. Instead of doing that i will create one function in that i will pass string as a object reference so i will be able to access the function

Comment: You really don't want to. And if you really, really must, then use a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: If you already have an instance of you object, why dont you want to use it?

Comment: I know it is a bad practice. My question is , Is der any possibility C# has?

Comment: I saw some example using System.Reflection in c#. but i am not good in c#

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no such way to do so.

I really interested to know why you need that, Please do reply in comment.